# Watchdog library isn't identified

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-watchdog, file-monitoring

I'm trying to create a file monitoring program using watchdog. However, my VSCode won't identify the library.

[Library isn't recognized - image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFoS8.png)

I have already ran *pip install watchdog* on my powershell and it displays: *Requirement already satisfied: watchdog in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (2.1.6)*, and when I run *watchmedo --help* to check, it's not recognized.

How do I fix this?

[EDIT] *Watchmedo* is installed and seems to be running properly. However, I can't see in which python environment it is when I run `watchmedo --help`

[Watchmedo without python environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc0Ty.png)

Comment: A small code example and the error you're facing would help to understand the problem in more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the `watchdog` in the global environment. Please check which python environment you have selected when you execute `watchmedo --help`. You can open the cmd out of the VSCode to execute `watchmedo --help`.

Comment: I can't see any python environments when I run `watchemdo --help`. Take a look at the image I linked in the main question above.